# How to achieve fast deallocation for objects in STL containers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-management, c++11

> **TL/DR**: How can a large `std::vector<std::string>` achieve such fast deallocation when compiled with release settings on Visual Studio 2012 RC?

I have written a class `strung` that behaves similarly to `std::string` as an exercise, implementing basic copy- and move semantics.

```
class strung
{
private:
    size_t length_;
    char* data_;

public:
    // -------- Constructors --------

    strung() : length_(0), data_(nullptr) {};

    strung(const char* c_str)
    {
        length_ = strlen(c_str);
        data_ = new char[length_];
        ::std::copy(c_str, c_str + length_, data_);
    };

    inline explicit strung(size_t length) : length_(length)
    {
        data_ = new char[length_];
    };

    strung(size_t length, char value) : length_(length)
    {
        data_ = new char[length_];
        ::std::fill(data_, data_ + length_, value);
    };

    // -------- Copy/move-constructors --------

    strung(const strung& old)
    {
        data_ = new char[old.length_];
        ::std::copy(old.data_, old.data_ + old.length_, data_);
        length_ = old.length_;
    };

    strung(strung&& old)
    {
        data_ = old.data_;
        length_ = old.length_;
        // Even though it is a rvalue, its destructor will still be called,
        // so we would like to prevent our data from being freed.
        old.data_ = nullptr;
    };

    // -------- Assignment operators --------

    inline strung & operator =(const strung& old)
    {
        if (this != &old)
        {
            delete[] data_;
            data_ = new char[old.length_];
            ::std::copy(old.data_, old.data_ + old.length_, data_);
            length_ = old.length_;
        }
        return *this;
    };

    strung & operator =(strung&& old)
    {
        if (this != &old)
        {
            delete[] data_;
            data_ = old.data_;
            length_ = old.length_;
            old.data_ = nullptr;
        }
        return *this;
    };

    // -------- Array operators (no bounds checking by design) --------

    inline char& operator[](size_t pos)
    {
        return data_[pos];
    };

    inline const char& operator[](size_t pos) const
    {
        return data_[pos];
    };

    // -------- Insertion operator for `ostream`s --------

    inline friend ::std::ostream &operator<<(::std::ostream &out, const strung& source)
    {
        out.write(source.data_, source.length_);
        return out;
    };

    // -------- Various functions --------

    inline const size_t length() const
    {
        return length_;
    }

    // -------- Poor man's iterators --------

    char* begin()
    {
        return data_;
    };

    char* end()
    {
        return data_ + length_;
    };

    // -------- Destructor --------

    inline ~strung()
    {
        delete[] data_;
    };
};
```

I tried comparing the performance of `std::string` and `strung` using this code:

```
double time(const std::function<void(void)> &func)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    func();
    auto total = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now()-t1);
    return static_cast<double>(total.count()) / 1000000.;
}

template<typename T>
void test(const int num)
{
    double allocation_time, full_time;

    full_time = time([&] {
        std::vector<T> container;

        allocation_time = time([&] {
            container.reserve(num);

            for (int i=0; i < num; i++)
            {
                container.emplace_back(rand() % 10 + 1,'\0');

                for (char &chr : container.back())
                    chr = ('A' + rand() % ('Z' - 'A' + 1) );
            }
        });
    });

    std::cout << "Full time: " <<  full_time << " miliseconds" << std::endl 
        << "Allocation time: " << allocation_time << " miliseconds" << std::endl 
        << "Deallocation time: " << full_time - allocation_time << " miliseconds" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "-------- std::string --------" << std::endl;
    test<std::string>(500000);
    std::cout << "-------- strung --------" << std::endl;
    test<strung>(500000);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And these were the results:

**Debug (x86-64)**

```
-------- std::string --------
Full time: 51050.9 miliseconds
Allocation time: 1853.11 miliseconds
Deallocation time: 49197.8 miliseconds
-------- strung --------
Full time: 52404 miliseconds
Allocation time: 4886.28 miliseconds
Deallocation time: 47517.7 miliseconds
```

**Release (x86-64):**

```
-------- std::string --------
Full time: 113.007 miliseconds
Allocation time: 107.006 miliseconds
Deallocation time: 6.0004 miliseconds
-------- strung --------
Full time: 47771.7 miliseconds
Allocation time: 356.02 miliseconds
Deallocation time: 47415.7 miliseconds
```

---

Allocation speeds are understandable, since I didn't really do much optimization on the class, but deallocation speeds are more intriguing.

Testing on Debug settings indicates that deallocation is similarly complex for both `std::string` and `strung` (though still very slow), but testing on Release settings makes deallocation for `std::string` very very fast, while `strung` stays exactly the same. What does `std::string` do to achieve such fast deallocation, considering that `strung`'s destructor is almost trivial.

At first I thought that `std::string` is optimized into a nop, so deallocation is not performed at all, but when I removed `strung`'s destructor, the latter was still much faster, so this is probably not a case.

I would like my deallocation to be fast, so what am I to do achieve similar deallocation speeds?

Comment: Didn't check the whole code... maybe the short string optimization of std::basic_string? Try bigger strings

Comment: Just a small comment -- the semicolons after all the function definitions in the `strung` class are unnecessary.

Comment: Note that as it is your `time` function measures the dispatch time of `std::function`. You might want to declare it as e.g. `template<typename Func> double time(Func&& func);` instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Microsoft's `std::string` implementation uses something called "small string optimization". What this means is that `std::string` actually contains a 15-character string (a `char[16]`). If it is given a string shorter than 16 characters, then it stores it in that internal memory. So there is no dynamic memory allocation done in these cases.

Your `strung` *always* dynamically allocates the string. Which means that its destructor will always deallocate it. `std::string`, if small enough, will do neither.

Comment: Wow, it is exactly that! When I use a fixed length of 150, my implementation is actually faster. Thank you!

Comment: @DeadMG: It's 16 / the character's size. So a wstring would only allow 7 characters + NULL.

Comment: @NicolBolas Shouldn't it depend on the systems pointer size? start-, end-, capacity pointer + some flag... usally 16bytes. dunno..

Comment: @hansmaad: Microsoft's `std::string` uses ptr+size+capacity, rather than three pointers.